# Is it possible in GCM/FCM to get last activity or if the user is connected?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am using GCM in my android project, the connection is XMPP, I wonder if there is a way to know if the user is currently connected from within the server service?

One way to do it is that I can send the user a ping and wait for a reply to see if he is connected but I was hoping for a better solution like to query GCM directly and it will tell you if the user is currently online or his last activity date.

I am trying to avoid using socket.io or signalr, because it will add load to the server specially if you have like half million users who are pinging the server regulary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you are looking for is not very well advertised, but it exist!

```
HEADERS: Authorization:key=SERVER-KEY
GET: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/GCM-TOKEN?details=true
```

Full documentation here: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

Comment: thank you, this api looks like what i was looking for, i don't have time to try it now however am gna mark this as correct answer

Comment: after testing this, unfortunately, it does not provide the connection time, only the date